# What happens when setInterval is called within a useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have following react component.

```
function App() {

  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      setCounter(counter+1)
    }, 3000)
  }, [counter]);

  console.log(counter)

  
  return (
    <div>
      hi
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And I get a result like

> 0
>
> 1
>
> 1
>
> 2
>
> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
> ...

I Do understand that with each setCounter call the component get re-rendered and per each render the useEffect callback get re-created. My question is should not that read the count value of the each render at the time by resulting

> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ....

Comment: You never cancel the previous intervals you set; there are more and more as time goes by, closed over different values of counter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But still should not that read the count value of the each render at the time. So the result should be

Yes it does but you are setting up a `setInterval` call that captures that value of counter and repeats `setCounter(counter + 1)` every 3 seconds. So every 3 seconds the counter will reset to the value captured when you set up the interval plus one. Every time it does, the effect hook will fire again and setup a new callback repeated every 3 seconds.

Did you mean to use `setTimeout` ?

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setCounter(counter+1)
    }, 3000)
  }, [counter]);

// Output: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ....
```

Comment: Thanks,  I get it now. Actually i wanted to set Intervals, I should have omitted the counter from deps list and make it run only once. I updated my code to have few console logs to see what is going on. Should have done this before posting the question :) Anyway I posted the way I solved my question as an answer

Comment: Ah. That is probably more efficient that running a hook at least every 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

To understand what is going on I added few `console.log` to the code. As Accepted answer explains

> setInterval call that captures that value of counter and repeats setCounter(counter + 1) every 3 seconds.

To fix this I added an empty array to the deps list to register a setInterval only once and passed a callback to setCounter to capture the current state value

```
function App() {

  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      setCounter((storedCounter) => storedCounter+1 )
      console.log(counter, 'captured value')
    }, 3000)
  }, []);

  console.log(counter, ' state')


  return (
    <div>
      hi
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image]